# Ranking all data in Php PDO

Tags: php, while-loop, ranking

I have been truggeling to rank user by phone number and booking status. for example, if i 5 users have booked for today i need to get all users from db which i did successfully with while loop, but the ranking doesn't wanna work when i search by user's phone number. I hope my question is clear and thanks in advance.

Code Below...

```
public function checkup($number){
    $pdo = $this->pdo;
    $checkUpDate = date('Y-m-d');
    $statsDate = date('Y-m-d');

    $get_all = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE booking_date =? AND booking_status = 0');
    $get_all->execute([$statsDate]);
    $stats = $get_all->rowCount();
    while($checkUpData = $get_all->fetch()){
    $chk_num = $checkUpData['phone'].',';
    $chk_id = $checkUpData['id'];

    $array = array($chk_num => $chk_id);
    $keys = array_keys( $array );
    $rank = array_search( $number, $keys );

    }
    printf( "You rank %d of %d", ++$rank, count($array) );
    print(" - Please check again after 15 minutes.<br>");
```

Comment: Can you add sample data to your question?

Comment: You're overwriting the `$array`, `$keys` and `$rank` variables on each iteration in your loop. After the loop, they will only contain the values from the last iteration.

Comment: **This is my sample data:**

"29","James","0603178302","13:30","2019-10-14","0"
"28","Tladi","0303030333","13:30","2019-10-14","0"
"27","Earl","0606317821","12:30","2019-10-14","0"
"26","Tumi","0726317821","12:30","2019-10-14","0"
"25","Retha","0513178302","16:30","2019-10-14","1"
"24","Hloni","0806317821","16:30","2019-10-14","0"

Comment: I have wrapped print function inside while loop, but I have tried changing $arrays,$key and $rank; but now it's not working.